# Why is the newline character not printed on terminal after entering batch_mode?

Tags: tex-core, terminal-output

When TeX stops on an error, we can answer `Q`. In such case in the log file this is printed:

```
OK, entering \batchmode...
```

But on the terminal thsis is printed:

```
OK, entering \batchmode<terminal prompt>
```

Incidentally, if `R` or `S` is input instead of `Q`, terminal output is (ending with newline character):

```
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
```

```
OK, entering \scrollmode...
```

It is somewhat annoying that on the terminal a newline is not printed when `Q` is used. (Although `print_ln` is used after the code which prints the above line, it does not influence terminal output because `decr(selector)` is called before it.)

I can make the newline be added with this change:

```
@x
"Q":begin print_esc("batchmode"); decr(selector);
@y
"Q":begin print_esc("batchmode"); wterm_cr; term_offset:=0; decr(selector);
@z
```

Why did DEK decide not to output newline after `batchmode`?

Comment: I get a newline on windows. But beside this, I don't think that it makes so much sense to ask why it has been done. If you want to change it, make a feature request.

Comment: Most likely answer is something like: the terminals on PDP-10 that Knuth used at SAIL did not require a newline at the end of a program's terminal output; this was left as a system-dependent change (apparently changed on Windows per the previous comment).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The message `I can't find the PLAIN format file!` in tex.web appears right before tex terminates. But it explicitly puts newline character. This makes an empty line before shell prompt, which is inconsistent with, for example, `! End of file on the terminal... why?` Why such inconsistency?